# How to style multiple cell in Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm figuring out how to style multiple cell using cell range. see my code for my current code. Thanks in advance for those who want to help me.

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < ColumnList.length; counter++) {
    SXSSFCell cell = currentRow.createCell(counter);
    if (counter == 0) {
       cell.setCellValue(String.valueOf(rowNum));
       cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    } else {
      String columnValue = ColumnList[counter];                 
      String cellValue = rs.getString(columnValue);
      cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
      cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
    }
```

}

Comment: What isn't working with your code?

Comment: Hi Gagravarr,
Right now I'm adding on each cell style. what I'm trying to test if adding cell style at the end has better performance it terms of execution time. But  i cant figure it out by using cell range.

Comment: Nope, just style as you go, styles are stored in the file format on a per-cell level (it's an attribute / property of the cell when on disk)

Comment: @Gagravarr I found a better way. Instead looping per cell, I used setRowStyle which much better than per cell.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CellRangeAddress` on the [docs](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellRangeAddress.html) which has a constructor you could use:

```
CellRangeAddress(int firstRow, int lastRow, int firstCol, int lastCol)
```

Comment: @Alex Actually it might not. It might not be possible to apply styles to all cells in a range like this, without using a simple loop.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found a better way instead looping per cell, I used setRowStyle which much better than per cell.

Answer (score 0):

This is done. A better way of applying cellStyles in multiple cell is by row.
There is a setRowStyle on the docs which you can apply Styles in a row and loop until it reach the last row.